# Show that positive definite matrix $S$ can be factorised in particular way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, block-matrices

I would like to show that every positive definite matrix $S \in \mathbb R^{2d \times 2d}$ can be written as:
$$
  S = M M^T,
$$
where $M$ has the following form:
$$
  M = \Lambda \begin{bmatrix}
    I + AB & A \\
    B & I
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
with some positive diagonal matrix $\Lambda \in \mathbb R_+^{2d \times 2d}$, and arbitrary matrices $A, B \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$.

Optional: How do $A, B, \Lambda$ have to be picked given $S$?

Notes:

- From numerical experiments, I am pretty sure that it's true.
- I already know that the converse holds:
  For any given $A, B, \Lambda$ as above, $M$ has full rank, so $M M^T$ is positive definite.